# Python Selenium WebDriver JavaScript Table Iteration

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I've been playing with Beautiful Soup for awhile and it works great minus the javascript limitations. I am trying to use Selenium to bridge the gap in my toolbox. The site I am trying to scrape is http://www.5dimes.eu/livelines/livelines.aspx

**I should mentioned I am in windows and can't get QTWebKit to work which I've been told is an option as well.

The site requires you to click a checkbox in order for the table(s) to preview. Once I was able to get the table to preview, I assumed I was in the clear but alas no.

I tried to use

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
page = driver.get("http://www.5dimes.eu/livelines/livelines.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='l_26']").click()
html_source = driver.page_source
```

and was able to get the page to in fact click a link but the html_source didn't have the table data.

Several issues followed on testing.

1. The xpath id changes daily based on how many things are posted. One day it was 26 the next day it was 27 etc. Is there an alternate way to navigate to this checkbox either via class or text name?
2. Once the table is displayed, how can I extract this data?

I noticed in the class info that it mentioned a "hidden" attribute

```
<div id="divLoading" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" class="Hidden">
        <img id="imgLoading" src="images/scanning.gif">
    </div>
```

Could that be the source of the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
   L= find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='divl_25']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]");
```

It will return list of WebElements contains same locator.(i.e., first td of your table content)

For getting second td content you need to change the td index to two.

```
   L= find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='divl_25']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");
```

The above line will gives you all second td s in every row.

After getting list of WebElements iterate that list in loop and get text from each element. In this way you can get entire table data.

```
for ele in L:
        print ele.text;
```

I hope this is useful to you.

P.S : I don't know much about python, selenium-python bindings.

Comment: `Test.py", line 21, in <module>
    L1= find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='divl_26']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]");
NameError: name 'find_elements_by_xpath' is not defined`

Comment: Try something like this  -> L=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[@id='divl_25']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"))

Comment: `Test.py", line 20, in <module>
    L0=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[@id='divl_25']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"))
NameError: name 'By' is not defined`

Comment: I've edited answer just try like that. I don't know much about python-selenium syntax. but, this is the logic

Comment: ` L= find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='divl_25']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
NameError: name 'find_elements' is not defined`

Comment: @Santosharma thanks for the help. I'm willing to try anything!